# Flutter Firestore [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app I need to update my current user data but I have this issue [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found. how can I fix this

here my updateData() code

```
  void updateData() {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;


    FirebaseFirestore.instance.
    collection('users').
    doc(uid).
    update({"height": heightTextEditingController.text}).
    catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: the document does not exist, add a screenshot of ur database and do print(uid) and see what u get

Comment: I add screenshot

Comment: what does print(uid) give you?

Comment: I/flutter (16766): KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2  this but ı dont have an uid like this

Comment: and that's why it doesnt work

Comment: are you adding the uid as a document id?

Comment: I think so, I am new on flutter fire-store so i don't know much :D

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the `uid` as a document id when saving data to the database:

```
  var firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(
  {
    "name" : "john",
    "email" : "example@example.com",
    "height": 180
    "weight":70
  }).then((_){
    print("success!");
  });
```

Inside `doc()` pass the `uid` and then use `set()` to add the fields to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot of your Firestore so that we can see what's your Firestore directory names. Could be a spelling mistake.

Edit 1:

Found the mistake. It should be FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users') instead of ('user'). See below codes

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.
collection('users').
doc(uid).
update({"height": heightTextEditingController.text}).
catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}
```

Comment: I send screenshot

Comment: @alperborabay edited my answer. Please try again

Comment: sorry its my mistake its already like that I typed it wrong while writing here :D

Comment: @alperborabay Are you able to print the current user's uid? if you can't means you are not connected to the firebase/firestore. Check your pubspec as well for the cloud_firestore dependency

Comment: I think I cant print my current user because when I use tihs print(uid) flutter gave me this I/flutter (16766): KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2 and I dont have currentuser like this

Comment: How can I connect my currentUser with other way

Comment: @alperborabay oh that's because there is no such uid (KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2) in the 'users' collection. that is why you could not update. trying adding a new document (KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2) into the 'users' collection

Comment: @alperborabay You gotta note that when you create a new user using Firebase Auth, it doesnt automatically adds the 'uid' into Firestore, they are separated. So you have to create and call a method to add the 'uid' as a document into the 'users' collection

Comment: You are currently login to KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2. Inside firestore there is no 'KR8ScjsDfeZsFvjyK5qWkXSDsmI2' documents in 'users' collection. That is why you are unable to update

Comment: uploadUserInfo(userMap){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").add(userMap).catchError((e){print(e.toString());});
  }

Comment: is this true for add uid, I am using this when users sign up

Comment: Use the answer provided Peter Haddad to set this 'uid' document in the firestore. Then it will appear in the db